# non-constant variance of $\hat{\epsilon}$ against $\hat{y}$

Tags: r, regression, diagnostic

In Faraways Linear Models (2ed.) page 77, he mention: "when non-constant variance is seen in the plot of $\hat{\epsilon}$ against $\hat{y}$", a transformation of the response $y$ to $h(y)$ where $h()$(a comment on what h() means here is appreciated) can be chosen so that $\operatorname{var}(h(y))$ is constant."

Then he gives an example on how to consider $h$

$$h(y) = h(Ey) + (y-Ey)h'(Ey)+ \cdots \\ \operatorname{var}(h(y)) = 0+h'(Ey)2\operatorname{var}(y)+ \cdots$$
We ignore higher order terms. For $var(h(y))$to be constant we need

$$h'(Ey) \propto (\operatorname{var}(y))^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$
which suggests:
$$h(y) = \int\frac{dy}{\operatorname{var}(y)} == \int\frac{dy}{\text{SD}y}$$
(a comment on what the '$==$' means here is appreciated).

By an example with R, how exactly would this transformation plan out on data with non-constant variance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very next sentence in Faraway gives you two examples:

> For example if $\operatorname{var} y=\operatorname{var}\varepsilon\propto(Ey)^2,$ then $h(y)=\log y$ is suggested while if $\operatorname{var}\varepsilon\propto(Ey),$ then $h(y)=\sqrt{y}.$

Furthermore, on page 219 you can see an example of the logarithm transformation done in R:

```
lmodu <- lm(log(longevity) ~ activity, fruitfly)
```

I imagine the $==$ just means "is equivalent to", similar to $\equiv$ in logic.

Comment: How do we test for $var(y) = var(\epsilon)$, he uses the example of `var.test` before this paragraph, but he's testing the variances between residuals. Do we suppose something like ```var.test(data$response, residuals(lmod))``` where `lmod` is a fitted linear model?

Comment: Faraway prefers, and I think I agree with him, graphical methods to check for constant variance: `plot(fitted(lmod), residuals(lmod))` or `plot(<predictor>,residuals(lmod))`. You're looking for patterns. Does the spread tend to stay the same from left to right? If you see no discernable patterns, that's a good sign for that particular model.

Comment: oh I see, I agree also however I am working on a function that performs the calculations for these test to give some output for decisions prior to plotting. I might have got slightly confused with the notation and misguided myself with the dependent variable and the predictor. Thanks for showing me the example!

Comment: I have an additional question, what does it mean to plot $\hat{\epsilon}$ against $x_i$, I understand that $\hat{\epsilon}$ is the residuals, and $x_i$ are the independent variables? Therefore, plotting the residuals against the variables used in the model, something like ```plot(data$predictor, residuals(lmod))```? But because it's $x_i$ we plot against all the predictors used in the model? <- What is the importance behind this, or perhaps I should open a new post?

Comment: You've got it exactly: `plot(data$predictor, residuals(lmod)),` and you're looking for the same thing as when you do `plot(fitted(lmod), residuals(lmod))`: patterns. If you see random behavior, that's generally good.